# SQL Server - Transfering / Adopting only one name from Rows with same ID´s but different names

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison, max, string-length

I have the following problem:
     
My table looks like this.

```
   ID    Name
   1     Company LTD.
   1     Company Limited
   1     Company ltd
   2     Example Corp.
   2     Example Corporation
   ...
```

Since they are "different" names for the same company, I just decided to keep the longest name as my company name.

So my question is. How do I check for the longest one and at the same moment just keep one entry, e.g.

```
   ID    Name
   1     Company Limited
   2     Example Corporation
```

The table should look like this afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a `ROW_NUMBER()` with a `PARTITION` on the `ID` and ordering by the `LEN()` desc:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Id Order By Len(Name) Desc) As RN
    From    YourTable
)
Delete  Cte
Where   RN <> 1
```

*Note: This will physically remove the records from your table that are not the longest entry.  If you do not wish to physically remove them, and only `SELECT` the longest entries, use the following instead:*

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Id Order By Len(Name) Desc) As RN
    From    YourTable
)
Select  Id, Name
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for!´
Thought about it myself yesterday already.

Answer (score 0):

One more option with Ties...

```
select
top 1 with ties
id,name
from
table
order by
row_number() over (partition by id order by len(name))
```